# Can an "Employee Stock Purchase Program" artificially influence the company's stock price?

Tags: stocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I wait a few days to sell ESPP Stock?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8918/should-i-wait-a-few-days-to-sell-espp-stock)

My employer allows employees to buy company stock every six months (on Jan 1 and July 1) at a 15% discount.  Naturally, this seems like a good deal and I imagine there are many employees who participate.

I'm curious: How do you think a company's stock price is influenced, if at all, by such a purchasing program?  For example, is it possible that the shares could artificially go up/down by a few cents on Jan 1 and July 1 because of the fixed purchases that will be made on those days?